# Several lines of text inside a bootstrap progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add 2 or 3 lines of text to a bootstrap progress bar without success. It admits a span label for a line of text but I couldn't add more lines beneath that line.

I am trying to achieve something like this, one bar with several lines of text in it:

<===============text1================>
<===============text2================>

Note: I am using Bootstrap 3.

Note: The lines must be centered.

Comment: tried setting the height of the loading bar to `height: auto;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on [bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) then you have to define `progress` class to 100% in css.

Please follow the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Gururaj26/2vwmws51/) for the code.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks GURURAJ, I accepted your answer but I also wanted the text centered. It was my bad, I am updating the question. My solution is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gugol/5t2t8brf/)

Comment: Isn't it already text centered ? Check this - [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Gururaj26/2vwmws51/3/)

Comment: No, it is not centered by default. And your fiddle solution is not centered. It must be in the middle of the bar not in the middle of the progression bit.

Comment: And if you do like that how do you handle when it is dynamic ?